# What can we say about $A$ if $A^\top A = I_q$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in Mat_{r \times q}$. I know, if $r = q,$ each column of $A$ forms an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb R^q$. However, when $r \neq q$, what can we say about the columns/ rows of $A$?

Comment: You can say that the columns of $A$ are orthogonal.

Comment: Note that you need $r\ge q$ for this to be possible. :)

Comment: @A.Γ. How can we prove this/ what is the source of the proof?

Comment: The matrix elements in $A^TA$ are scalar products of the column of $A$. The diagonal elements are $1$'s means the columns are normalized. The off-diagonal elements are $0$'s means they are orthogonal.

Comment: @A.Γ. Could we ascertain anything about the rows? I guess we'd need to know what $AA^\top$ is.

Comment: Not much about the rows except that there are $q$ linearly independent.